# unable to import products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4

The first time I am hosting my Magento 2 version(2.3.4) website, I am facing here while uploading the product!

the error is :

1. Invalid value in Website column (website does not exist?) in a row(s): 1

[image: error image]

and this is my CSV file [sample file](http://trdev.com.au/exdata/)

[image: cdvsheet]

I have downloaded this sample file from the import section only

[image: sample file]

I have tried many solutions on the internet

what is the problem here, What I suppose to give value for 'product_websites' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of sample file , please create one product from backend and export that product and use that sample file !

this fix my problem